# URL not appending querystring when set to body of email message

Tags: c#, webforms

I am using a dictonary to perform a merge code replacment in a email notifcations emails work great but I am having a hell of a time with urls for some reason its not adding the query strings to the url even though the url is well formed.

```
 Dictionary<string, string> stringsToReplace = new Dictionary<string, string>();

 stringsToReplace.Add("{method}", method);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{full_name}", fullname);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{ipaddress}", GetIPAddress());
 stringsToReplace.Add("{query}", queryMessage);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{address}", address);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{user_name}", fullname);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{iva_ref}", caseRef);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{case_ref}", caseRef);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{optout}", OptionsText);
 stringsToReplace.Add("{regemail}", OptionsText);

 string linkreset = "<a href= '" + DomainUrl + "?email=" + customerEmail + "&uid=" + userId + "'> Reset Password" + "<a/>";
 stringsToReplace.Add("{email}", customerEmail.ToString());

 stringsToReplace.Add("{reset_link}", string.Format("Please click the link below to reset your password <br /> {0}", linkreset));

string verifyPassword = "<a href= '" + verificationUrl + "?email=" + customerEmail + "&uid=" + userId + "'> Verify Password" + "<a/>";

stringsToReplace.Add("{verification_link}", string.Format("Please click the link below to verify your password <br /> {0}", verificationUrl));

bodyMessage = bodyMessage.MultipleReplace(stringsToReplace);
```

I just dont c why my paramerters are not being brought through to verifyPassword  when i look at the url its stops at .aspx and no query strings in the hyper link

Comment: Are you sure you need to have the {} in the keys in the map?

Comment: Hi the other maps are working fine bob so they are i think its something to do with my quotes in the urls im using {} keys to parse text out of pre drafted email stored in a db field

Comment: is verificationURL blank? Shouldn't it be linkreset? I can't see where you're adding verifyPassword to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is faulty;

```
string verifyPassword = "<a href= '" + verificationUrl + "?email=" + customerEmail + "&uid=" + userId + "'> Verify Password" + "<a/>";

stringsToReplace.Add("{verification_link}", string.Format("Please click the link below to verify your password <br /> {0}", verificationUrl));
```

looks like it should be

```
string verifyPassword = "<a href= '" + verificationUrl + "?email=" + customerEmail + "&uid=" + userId + "'> Verify Password" + "<a/>";

stringsToReplace.Add("{verification_link}", string.Format("Please click the link below to verify your password <br /> {0}", verifyPassword ));
```

note - verifyPassword not vertificationUrl in the replace.